# Question marks showing in ls of directory even with root

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, docker

If I do `ls -alt` in any folder i get the following. Even with the files or folders i create with root. Commands such as `stat filename` returns `Operation not permitted`. Any idea what causes this?

```
[root@011319292d9c ~]# pwd
/root
[root@011319292d9c ~]# ls -alt
ls: cannot access '.': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '..': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '.bash_profile': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '.tcshrc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '.bashrc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '.bash_logout': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'test-file-i-created-as-root': Operation not permitted
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .bash_logout
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .bash_profile
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .bashrc
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .cshrc
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .tcshrc
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test-file-i-created-as-root
```

P.S. This happened inside a docker container which I started it with bash from docker image with redhat 8.5 as follows for debugging purposes:

```
docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash <Image-ID>
```

Important to mention that I do not have a problem when i attached running container which is started with `docker run`

```
docker exec -ti <Image-ID> /bin/bash
```

Host OS of container:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux" 
VERSION="8.5 (Ootpa)" 
-------------
uname -a 
Linux 3985430895d8 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM custom-docker-image:tag

RUN microdnf update

RUN install-custom-server-modules.sh

CMD ['start-script.sh']
```

*(!)* As soon as i removed the line `RUN microdnf update` from Dockerfile i do not have the problem anymore.

Comment: What's the host OS? Which Docker image? Docker version info? Steps to reproduce?

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.5 (Ootpa)"
uname -a
Linux 3985430895d8 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Steps to reproduce: As soon as i removed the following line from Dockerfile i do not have the problem anymore. 
`RUN microdnf update`

Comment: OK. `microdnf` is a lightweight implementation of the dnf package manager written in C. It probably does something to the container FS, which I'd like to reproduce. Please edit your post, adding all info to your post, _including the Dockerfile_.

Comment: Edited the post. Important to mention that I do not have a problem when i attached running container which is started with `docker run`.
`docker exec -ti <Image-ID> /bin/bash`